# Cannot set interface (NIC) up: Atheros ath9k_htc in Ubuntu 18, kernel 5.4.0-128

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, network-manager, nic

I am trying to use the wifi adaptor TP-Link TL-WN722N (which user Atheros ath9k_htc).
But I can't have it go up.

```
 ~$ sudo ip link set wlxc4e9841384f9 up
```

returns with no error, but:

```
wlxc4e9841384f9: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

stays down.

The Ubuntu  (Gnome) "Settings -> WiFi" window does not show it either.

Here is some more information:

> ~$ uname -a

```
Linux 5.4.0-128-generic #144~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sep 22
```

11:08:41 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> ~$ lsb_release -a

```
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS  Release:    18.04

~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
~$ sudo dmesg | grep wlx
[   17.046245] ath9k_htc 3-2:1.0 wlxc4e9841384f9: renamed from wlan0
~$ nmcli radio wifi on
```

(does not help)

> ~$ nmcli d

```
 DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
    wlxc4e9841384f9  wifi      disconnected  --          
    eno1             ethernet  unavailable   --          
    lo              loopback   unmanaged     --

~$ lsusb
... ...
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
... ...


~$ lsmod | grep ath
ath9k_htc              77824  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              475136  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common
ath                    36864  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
mac80211              856064  1 ath9k_htc
cfg80211              712704  4 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common,ath,mac80211

~$ dmesg | grep ath9k

[ 1894.858326] usb 3-2: ath9k_htc: Firmware       ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested 
[ 1894.858407] usbcore:registered new interface driver ath9k_htc 
[ 1895.329899] usb 3-2:ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008 
[ 1895.580352] ath9k_htc 3-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits 
[ 1895.806202] ath9k_htc 3-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4 
[ 1895.806205] ath9k_htc 3-2:1.0: FW RMW support: On 
[ 1895.830873] ath9k_htc 3-2:1.0 wlxc4e9841384f9: renamed from wlan0 
[ 2878.742250] usb 3-2: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size:
    51008 
[ 2878.992712] ath9k_htc 3-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
~$  sudo iw wlxc4e9841384f9 scan

Does not return anything

~$ nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY

Does not return anything

~$ modinfo ath9k_htc
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-128-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko
firmware:       ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw;     ath9k_htc/htc_7010-1.4.0.fw
description:    Atheros driver 802.11n HTC based wireless devices
license:        Dual BSD/GPL;       author: Atheros Communications
srcversion:     DC48CFECAAE9D63EBE6AEB4
alias:          usb:v0CF3p20FFd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
... ...
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,ath,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y   intree: Y
vermagic:       5.4.0-128-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signat:         PKCS#7   sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           debug: Debugging mask (uint);                           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable: Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int);    ps_enable:  Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_dev_fw: Use development FW version (int);       blink:  Enable LED blink on activity (int)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and: `sudo dmesg | grep wlx`

Comment: Is it correct that you are running Ubuntu Core 18? That is the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version number.

Comment: @chili555: done

Comment: @David: I am running: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, kernel: 5.4.0-128